# Test for prime number with javascript

Tags: javascript, discrete-mathematics

I really want to know why this code is not working. Can some one give me the reason why {2,3,5,7} cannot be used as the basis for testing prime numbers. The code below tries to sum all the prime numbers below 2million

```
var x = 2 + 3 + 5 + 7;
for(i = 2; i<2000000; i++){
    if(Number.isInteger(i/2) || Number.isInteger(i/3) || Number.isInteger(i/5) || Number.isInteger(i/7)){

    }else{

        x = x + (i);
    }
}
 console.log(x);
```

Comment: i is not declared

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt - It's initialized, it's just undeclared, leading to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - okay, being a Java developer I tend to use those terminologies..edited my comment.

Comment: Is `11 * 11` divisible by any of those numbers (**hint**: no)?  A better and efficient approach is to use something called the ["Sieve of Eratosthenes"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: Thats true. I ought to declare i but It still works that way

Comment: @c1moore. You are right. Thats just what I want to clarify. {2,3,5,7} is not a basis for testing for prime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As T.J.Crowder stated, `i` is not declared; however, I don't think that's your only issue.  You're using a small subset of prime numbers as the basis of finding all primes.  This won't work.  A few examples of numbers that cannot be divided by {2, 3, 5, 7} but are still not prime include:

```
121 = 11 * 11
169 = 13 * 13
...
```

A more accurate approach is to use what is called the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).  There are other approaches, but their complexity is much worse.

A variation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes is called Euler's Sieve (or the Sieve of Euler).  It is slightly more efficient by taking several short-cuts and reducing the number of computations.